# Shopware 6: Extension tab is not showing

Tags: plugins, shopware, shopware6

We set up a shopware 6 (6.4.8.2) store on a staging environment. However we have a problem that it is not showing the Extensions Entry (or I think German would be Erweiterungen) in the Side bar as you can see in the screen shot.

[image: Shopware Admin Side Navigation]

Also there is, no such entry in the Settings (DE: Einstellungen). Is there any configuration how this can be enabled/disabled? My web search for this was not successful so far...

UPDATE:
When trying to install a plugin in the "Einrichtungs-Assistent" (Setup Assistant) I can see an error in the console:

> app.js?16413948306127883:1 TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'getMyExtensions')
> at e. (app.js?16413948306127883:1:5170787)
> at u (vendors-node.js?16413948281562417:1:663772)
> at Generator._invoke (vendors-node.js?16413948281562417:1:663560)
> at Generator.next (vendors-node.js?16413948281562417:1:664197)
> at n (vendors-node.js?16413948281562417:1:1500571)
> at s (vendors-node.js?16413948281562417:1:1500782)
> at vendors-node.js?16413948281562417:1:1500841
> at new Promise ()
> at e. (vendors-node.js?16413948281562417:1:1500722)
> at e. (app.js?16413948306127883:1:5171129)

Which when looking into the code might indicate that the extensionStoreActionService is undefined, however I have no clue what could be the reason for this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The extensios or "Erweiterungen" entry should be there in any event - there is no configuration setting to show or hide it.

I guess there is something broken with your installation. Did you check the Console or Network tab on your browser's DevTools? I bet you'll see some JS errors that might help you to further identify the problem.

It could be related to some plugin - you may also want to deacivate plugins step-by-step for testing.

Comment: You are right there is a 500 shown in the network, which is related to some bundle related to a plugin, if removing that solves the issue I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Removing the related plugin did actually not solve the issue, there is no more 500 now in the console, however the "Erweiterungen" entry is still not showing up

Comment: Check the server / Shopware logs to find out the root cause for those 500 errors and post the error message

Comment: before it was telling that it could not find several public/bundles/<pluginname>/<filename>. I uninstalled the plugin, now the 500 is gone.  but the extension entry is still not there, I will try to find out how to find some logs on the server

Comment: I updated the question with an error which is thrown when trying to run the setup assistant and activating an extension. Also when clicking the activate extensions in the last step of the manager it just shows an error, but there is no call/error being logged in network/console

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue, where the plugin bundles where missing too.
Solved it by running `bin/console assets:install` from CLI to re-export them.

But I had not the error message, that you've got.